# How to choose a partition to prove integrability?

Tags: integration

I have to prove the integrability of functions using the darboux integral, but i dont know how to choose the partition. For example, i need to prove that the integral of x from 0 to b is $\frac{b^{2}}{2}$ but I dont know which partition i have to use. Usually, for an intervalo $[0,1]$ you use $P= \left[0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},...,\frac{n}{n}\right]$, but for $[0,b]$? So that The integral will be $\frac{b^{2}}{2}$ ?

Comment: you may prove with $\left[0,\frac{b}{n},\frac{2b}{n},\frac{3b}{n},.....,\frac{nb}{n}=b\right]$ , this is a riemann partition. Lol

Comment: I already tried with that partition, didnt work

Answer (score 1):

To prove integrability, note that the difference between the upper and lower sums (for the identity function on $[0,b]$) is $\frac{b^2}{n}$. This is simply because considering a partition of equal subintervals (length $\frac{b}{n})$ the difference between the upper and lower sums on each *subinterval* is $\frac bn \cdot \frac bn = \frac{b^2}{n^2}$. We have $n$ of these. This can be made less then $\epsilon$ as a consequence of the Archimedian property

To prove that the integral it is $\frac{b^2}{2}$, I'll just give you a hint. Consider both the upper sums and the lower sums and let $n \to \infty$. There's a little bit of algebra, and you must use the formula for the sum of the first $n$ numbers. Once you have solved this, an exercise: formally, why can we disregard partitions which do not have equal subintervals?